# Probability of $2$ boys in a family.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a family there are 3 children with minimum $1$ boy.What is the probability there are exactly $2$ boys in the family?

I think I have to use combinatorics to solve this problem.
I have solved some problem in probability but this one seems to me totally different.Answer of this problem is 3/7.But I cant't figure it out.Please help me.

Comment: Try to enumerate all possibilities.

Comment: Exactly $2$ boys in the family? Or at least $2$ boys?

Comment: exactly two boys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $2^3=8$ combinations, with no restrictions. There are $7$ combinations with at least a boy, because there is only $1$ combination with no boys (namely, three girls).

The number of combinations with exactly two boys is $\binom 32=3$. (These are $BBG$, $BGB$ and $GBB$). Then the probability is $3/7$.

Comment: In 7 combinations aren't $GBB$, $BBG$ and $BGB$ same?

Comment: Not at all. If you think that they are the same just because they have the same number of boys, think at this extreme example: if you toss a coin 1000 times, which is more probable? 1 head or 500 heads?

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional probability. You are given there is at least 1 boy and asked to find the probability that there are two boys.

Let even $A=$ three children with 2 boys, $B=$three children with at least 1 boy, then

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

where, $$P(A\cap B)=\binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$$
$$P(B)=1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$$

Hence $P(A|B) =\frac{3}{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

What can happen if a family is blessed with $3$ children? Possibilities:

- BBB
- BBG
- BGB
- BGG
- GBB
- GBG
- GGB
- GGG

Each of these events have the same probability. Note that $7$ of these possibilities remain if it is demanded that at least one of the children is a boy. The last (GGG) falls off. In how many of these  $7$ possibilities are there exactly $2$ boys? Just counting we find: in $3$. So the answer to your question is $\frac{3}{7}$.

Counting was enough here and on purpose I did not use combinatorics. That can be used to find out the mentioned values $7$ and $3$. For that see the answer of @ajotatxe.